# How do I change Markdownlint settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

The [Markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint) plugin in Visual Studio Code is raising an [MD007 error](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/v0.7.0/doc/Rules.md#md007---unordered-list-indentation).

I'd like to update the setting but can't work out how to find the `options.config` referred to in the markdownlint documentation?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The trick is explained in the [vscode-markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/vscode-markdownlint#configure) repo (diff from the primary [markdownlint repo](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint)):

> Rules can also be configured using Code's support for [user and workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

1. In Visual Studio Code, open `File -> Preferences -> Settings` ***or*** use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Edit the `User Settings` tab on the right to something like this:

   ```
   "markdownlint.config": {
       "default": true,
       "MD007": { "indent": 4 }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 21):

I'd like to provide an update on this as of VS Code v1.28.2., markdownlint v0.21.0.

Per the official documentation, to provide a custom configuration, you simply put a `.markdownlint.json` at the root directory of your project.

For example, consider the following folder structure:

```
.
│   .markdownlint.json
├───docs
│       sitesetup.md
└───src
```

and now consider the following content in `.markdownlint.json`:

```
{
    "default": true,
    "MD007": false
}
```

VS Code would now load that custom markdownlint configuration when editing any markdown files within that folder hierarchy.

You can find the official documentation [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint).

Comment: You can also [use YAML format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint#configure) instead of JSON here - the config file name must then be either `.markdownlint.yaml` or `.markdownlint.yml`. The avantage is you'll be able to add comments on why some rule was disabled (YAML supports comments whereas JSON does not)

Comment: If you prefer JSON but still want comments, you can use `.markdownlint.jsonc` (JSON with Comments.

Comment: Forgot to add: the big advantage of using `.json` or `.jsonc` in VS Code is full IntelliSense - very handy for working with configs like this.

Comment: Exactly how do you open the folder or workspace? This did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

With markdownlint 0.29, I wasn't able to get this working by using the rule name. On the [documentation](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/master/doc/Rules.md#md007---unordered-list-indentation), there's an alias that I had to use instead, `ul-indent`. My settings.json file ended up looking like:

```
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "markdownlint.config": {
        "default": true,
        "no-inline-html": { "allowed_elements": ["pre"] },
        "ul-indent": { "indent": 4 }
    }
}
```